# Randomly drop n-groups from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, random, drop

I have a dataframe with 15466 rows × 125 columns. Column "Subject ID" (15466 rows) contains 400 unique ID's, where each of ID's appears approximately 40 times. I want to drop random 10 Subjects from my dataframe (cca 400 rows). So far i tried this:

```
trial = df.groupby(['Subject_ID']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(10))
```

but i realized this function takes random 10 rows from each Subject_ID instead of 10 gropups/Subject_ID's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to randomly select 10 ID's, then boolean index using `isin` to filter them out from your `DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np

exclude_ids = np.random.choice(df['Subject_ID'].unique(), 10)

df_new = df[~df['Subject_ID'].isin(exclude_ids)]
```